# Converting BFS to Djikstra to find the shortest path

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

How can I convert the following BFS algorithm to find the shortest path using Djikstra?  I know that I need to update distances of neighbors, but I am confused on how exactly to extend the following BFS with it. The constraint is we can move only along L shaped paths between two nodes.

```
from collections import deque

N = 8
board_p = [[(-1,-1) for f in range(0,N)] for i in range(0,N)]

def Adjacents(u):    
    adj = []
    for e in [(-2,-1),(-2,1),(2,1),(2,-1),(-1,-2),(1,-2),(-1,2),(1,2)]:        
        v = (u[0] + e[0], u[1] + e[1])
        if v[0] >= 0 and v[0] < N and v[1] >= 0 and v[1] < N: adj.append(v)
    return adj;

def Moves(s,t):
    q = deque()
    q.append(s)
    board_p[s[0]][s[1]] = s # "root" of BFS-traversal points to it self (avoid loop over "back-edge" to s)
    while q:
        u = q.popleft()
        if u == t: break
        for v in Adjacents(u):
            if board_p[v[0]][v[1]] == (-1,-1):
                board_p[v[0]][v[1]] = u
                q.append(v)

    # walk the path back (using parent "pointers")
    path = [(t)]    
    while t != s:
        t = board_p[t[0]][t[1]]
        path.append(t)

    path.reverse()
    return path


print(Moves((1,1),(5,5)))
```

Comment: Dijkstra only makes sense when there are edge weights. If there are no edge weights (or equivalently, if every edge has the same weight), then does not differ from BFS. So if you want to adapt your code to Dijkstra, should first think about what kind of edge weights you want to use.